# Send data from Windows Forms application to Window Service

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, ipc

I have a Windows Form where a user can enter data. This data, a complex struct, has to be communicated to a Window Service.

How can I solve this problem in C#?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618098/send-string-commands-or-bytes-to-a-windows-service-when-running) helps?

Comment: There are tons of solutions here, but one approach would be to leverage MSMQ. You would write to an MSMQ when the user is done entering the information and your Windows service would read periodically from that MSMQ to find new messages.

Comment: [Here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication)'s a good WCF tutorial, that's what I would use.

Comment: Why four upvotes? What did you try? Please research "inter-process communication" or IPC. Like @neo says, there are too many ways of solving this to write in an answer.

Comment: well, i followed a tutorial on wcf, actually i don't like how it works, is not straight forward to me, besides my service should be local, i don't need the internet. Maybe wcf is the solution, but i was hoping in something like executeCommand

Answer (score 2):

There are four ways to Interact with the windows service.

1. Through Windows Registry
2. Through WMI
3. Through Command
4. Through interop

Here you can get more [Details.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Yousafi/allow-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop/)

Answer (score -1):

If you Right click on the References section in the solution explorer, you will see a menu item for adding a service reference.  Once you set that up, you would just reference the service via the new keyword and its name.

Comment: If you need a reason for downvote then just read the question again

Comment: What @Sriram so kindly tries to explain, this question is about communicating with a **Windows** Service, not a WCF Service.

Comment: I assumed that the OP did not know the difference.  In the original request it said something about him being a new programmer, and I guessed that he wanted to communicate with a custom service not an actual windows service.